# How to always get a leading 0 in robot framework DateTime

Tags: robotframework, python-datetime

I am currently trying to figure out how to always get a leading 0 when getting current date time.

The following is the way I am currently doing it:

```
${date} =   Get Current Date  result_format=datetime
${dateyear}=  Convert To String    ${date.year}
${datemonth}=  Convert To String    ${date.month}
${dateday}=  Convert To String    ${date.day}
${datehour}=  Convert to string  ${date.hour}
${dateminute}=  Convert to string  ${date.minute}
```

The problem is that when I get date.day/minute/hour/, I get back 1-9 instead of 01-09. I am using the values to enrich a json, which expects 2 characters for each, so passing 1 results in an error, while passing 01 will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zfill() function to pad strings:

```
${dateminute}=  Set Variable    5
${dateminute}=  Evaluate        '${dateminute}'.zfill(2)
```